# Twilio not calling RecordingStatusCallback when recording completed

Tags: twilio

Twilio is seeing the RecordingStatusCallback request as it is populated in the call log. However, it doesn't actually POST to my endpoint. I've tried using my server as the endpoint, I've tried using a public facing mock endpoint. However Twilio is not making requsts to the specified endpoint URL when the recording is completed.

This is what Twilio is receiving, note it is getting the RecordingStatusCallback url.

```
POST
Request URL
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC9ef59c28fad/Calls.json
ParametersShow Raw
Transcribe  "false"
Method  "POST"
RecordingStatusCallbackEvent    "completed"
RecordingStatusCallbackMethod   "POST"
RecordingStatusCallback "https://back.theurl.org/recording_status_callback"
AccountSid  "AC9939959c28fad"
Twiml   "<Response><Redirect method=\"POST\">https://back.theurl.org/call_amd_handle</Redirect></Response>"
StatusCallbackMethod    "POST"
AsyncAmd    "false"
```

This is how I'm creating the call

```py
call = client_twilio.calls.create(
    twiml=f'<Response><Redirect method="POST">https://back.theurl.org/call_amd_handle</Redirect></Response>',
    machine_detection="Enable",
    to=call_input.call_to,
    from_=call_input.call_from,
    recording_status_callback='https://back.theurl.org/recording_status_callback',
    recording_status_callback_event='completed'
)
```